# What is the influence of `use utf8` on `Encode`?

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I am hunting a wide-character problem in our DB routines, and stumbled upon the following oddity:

```
use utf8;

use Encode;

my $x = "ö";

my $decoded  = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $x);

my $encoded = Encode::encode('UTF-8', $decoded);

my $redecoded = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $encoded);

{
    use bytes;
    printf "original: %vx\n", $x;
    printf "decoded: %vx\n", $decoded;
    printf "encoded: %vx\n", $encoded;
    printf "redecoded: %vx\n", $redecoded;
}
```

Executing this script gives:

```
original: c3.b6
decoded: ef.bf.bd
encoded: ef.bf.bd
redecoded: ef.bf.bd
```

I do not think that 0xef 0xbf 0xbd is valid UTF-8. If I remove the `use utf8` statement, the output is, as expected:

```
original: c3.b6
decoded: c3.b6
encoded: c3.b6
redecoded: c3.b6
```

So why is `use utf8;` changing the decoding semantics?

Comment: `ef.bf.bd` are UTF-8 bytes for  `�` (U+FFFD,  *Replacement Character*). You use `Encode` methods in a weird way:  `Encode::encode` is string to octets while `Encode::decode` is octets to string… https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode#THE-PERL-ENCODING-API

Answer (score 3):

`use utf8` tells Perl to decode the script using UTF-8 instead of ASCII. It has no effect on Encode. You are getting different results because you are passing different strings to `decode`.

You failed to notice this because of your incorrect use of `use bytes;`. (To be clear, using `use bytes;` is *always* incorrect.) Let's remove that and run your program again.

Specifically, I'll use the following:

```perl
printf "original: %vx\n", $x;
printf "decode('UTF-8', %vx): %vx\n", $x,       $decoded;
printf "encode('UTF-8', %vx): %vx\n", $decoded, $encoded;
printf "decode('UTF-8', %vx): %vx\n", $encoded, $redecoded;
```

---

With `use utf8;`:

```
original: f6
decode('UTF-8', f6): fffd
encode('UTF-8', fffd): ef.bf.bd
decode('UTF-8', ef.bf.bd): fffd
```

With `use utf8;`, Perl expects your program to be encoded using UTF-8, so your program has the equivalent of `my $x = "\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS}";`. Put differently, your string contains a single char with value 0xf6. This is not valid UTF-8, so you get garbage (U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) when you pass it to `decode 'UTF-8'`.

Replace `my $decoded  = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $x);` with `my $decoded = $x;` to get the expected results.

```
original: f6
decoded: f6
encode('UTF-8', f6): c3.b6
decode('UTF-8', c3.b6): f6
```

---

Without `use utf8;`:

```
original: c3.b6
decode('UTF-8', c3.b6): f6
encode('UTF-8', f6): c3.b6
decode('UTF-8', c3.b6): f6
```

Without `use utf8;`, Perl expects your program to be encoded using ASCII. It can't possibly contain `ö` as that is not an ASCII character. Instead, you have the equivalent of `my $x = "\xc3\xb6";` (because string literals are "8-bit clean"). This *is* valid UTF-8, and can thus be decoded.